# How can I copy/paste multiple key-frames in After Effects from different layers?

Tags: after-effects, keyframes

Is there a shortcut key to copy and paste After Effects keyframes? No, I don't want any kind of script to do so. I just want to move selected keyframes (they're multiple, not one, and they are in different layers) from a time to another time. But when I copy and paste them, AE pastes the whole layers!

Is there a way to copy them without copying the layers? Or at least a way to show only the keyframes in the timeline, so I can copy them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to copy-n-paste keyframes from multiple layers without using a script.

You can show the keyframes in a layer by hitting the <kbd>u</kbd> key. And then you can copy those keys layer by layer.

I'm not sure why you're opposed to using a script. I wrote one that can copy and paste keys from multiple layers in a single click (including copy-pasting with time reversal), and which is free and open source, you can [download it here](https://blob.pureandapplied.com.au/all-the-scripts/).

[image]